# iOS app Share a link on Tumblr

Tags: objective-c, tumblr

I am trying to post message to Tumblr through iOS app
written below code getting error.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"Titulo",@"title",
                            @"Este es el body",@"body",nil];

[[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] post:@"blogName" type:@"text" parameters:parameters callback:^(id var, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}];
```

getting following error

Error Domain=Request failed Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Request failed error 401.)"

Comment: An error 401 means you are not authorized. it's a standard HTTP result code.

Comment: Authenticated successfully using following code   [[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] authenticate:@"TumblrDemo" callback:^(NSError *error) {
        // You are now authenticated (if !error)
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
        
        [self getUserInfoTumblr];
       
    }];

Comment: Is there any other way to authenticate for post message.

Comment: hi @Coder_A_D did u get any solution?

Comment: yes I get the solution

Comment: @Coder_A_D: Could you tell me what you did the fix the 401 error? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not authenticated by Tubmlr.

You can refer to it here.
[Unable to post a photo using the Tumblr SDK example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049624/unable-to-post-a-photo-using-the-tumblr-sdk-example)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.